# Using join() to process an array in batches?

Tags: javascript

```
   var j = 0;
   var batchSize = 100;
   var json_left_to_process = json.length;
   while (json_left_to_process != 0) {
       var url_param = "";
       for (var i = j; i < j+batchSize; i++) {
           url_param += json[i].username + ",";
           json_left_to_process--;
       }
       j += batchSize;
       if (json_left_to_process < 100) {
           batchSize = json_left_to_process;
       }
       url_param.substring(0, url_param.lastIndexOf(','));

      //make ajax request
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/1.0/getFollowers.php",
                data: {param: url_param}
           )};
  }
```

I don't want to use

`url_param += json[i].username + ",";`

Instead, I want to say

```
newArray.push(json[i].username)
```

and then

```
url_param = newArray.join(',');
```

But I also want to process **up to** 100 elements in the array at a time. How can I do so?

EDIT: Sorry, I meant up to 100 elements, and then up to another 100 elements, and then up to another 100 elements, etc etc until you've processed everything.

Comment: just do it, where is the problem? 100 elements really shouldnt be any problem. but be aware that pure string concatenation is much faster!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a maximum lenght for URLs.

Comment: Right, so would a post work? See my edit to the question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to join **100** and then another **100** after then you can do it like this.

```
 newArray.slice(0, 100).join(',');
```

And then after that

```
 newArray.slice(100, 200).join(',');
```

You could create a function like this to automate it.

```
var array = [1...1000], // The array
    start = 0,          // The index to start at
    step  = 100;        // How many to get at a time

var getBatch = function() {
    var result = array.slice(start, start + step).join(',');
    start += step;  // Increment start
    return result;
};

getBatch(); // === 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 100
getBatch(); // === 100, 101, 102, ... 200
```

> **Documentation: [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**

Comment: The automation is really cool, except the problem is what if I have something like 777 elements?

Comment: Then it the last batch will return `77` and won't throw an error if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: Oh...? So I guess the slice() function handles error checking?

Comment: what do you mean, if i have this array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and do `array.slice(1, 10000);` it will return `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Ah, I see. So yea I was just asking if the slice() function makes sure that it won't do anything that is out of bounds

Comment: Also, I noticed that you should do the `start += step` part after the join and slice, because you'll never get indices 0..100

Answer (score 1):

i would use a modulo.

```
var i, start = 0;
var newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i <= json.length; i++) {

   // push whatever you want to newArray

   // if i is dividable by 100 slice that part out and join it
   if (i % 100 === 0) {
      console.log(newArray.slice(start, i).join(','));
      start = i;
   }
}
```